# Best practice to detect if service is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I need to detect if my service is available in the moment.

But, for some reason, I receive success in ajax() function when I try to reach some of the service methods even if the service is turned off.

I get an html page with 404 message as data in the success field.

My best guess is to use `typeof(data)` and compare it with string type.

But I think there must be a better solution.

Nothing special just $.ajax()

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '../Services/Service.svc/getItems',
            data: {},
            error: function (error) {

            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {

            },
            datatype: "json",
        });
```

Comment: could you include your js/ajax code? Thx

Comment: @WimOmbelets i did it, but don't think it helps

Comment: Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Note, docs give error callback as `error( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` "When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."

Comment: @Paul, error (Local Event)
This event is only called if an error occurred with the request (you can **never have both an error and a success callback** with a request). But i receive success every time. The difference is just data.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Just thinking.  Do you use nginx web server? Nginx can be told to ignore 404, send main page on bad request.

Comment: Where this is an issue, is if Nginx acts as the front desk to connect incoming visitor to either static files, or various backends.  If you try to test the backend, and the backend is down, then the nginx configuration matters.

Comment: @Paul i have access just to front-end, but my guess is C# WCF. Unfortunately, I can not change anything in the behavior of the server

Comment: OK then maybe your idea of examining `typeof(data)` is OK, if you expect `json` or `xml` on correct behavior and `string` means it is bad.

Comment: on a side note: that comma on the datatype line isn't necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with the info you provided.

If you are in control of the service (ie: you built it) then you could make the webserver return a 503 code when the service is unavailable. This is something the webserver should do when your service is down.

If not, then you need to check for the 404 error code instead that you are receiving right now and handle it gracefully in your code.

I'm assuming you are using jQuery for the client since you refer to the ajax() call. Here is a basic example to check the errorcode in the fail callback:

```
var serviceRequest = $.ajax(...);

serviceRequest.done(function(returnedData) {
    // Service is active and returning data.
});

serviceRequest.fail(function (xhr) {
    if(xhr.status == 404) {
        // handle this.
    }

    if(xhr.status == 503) {
        // handle this.
    }
});
```

Why you are receiving a 404 **and** hitting the success callback is something I have never seen before.